# Obtener el nombre de cualquier widget al pasar el cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Tengo el siguiente codigo con el que trate de hacer lo siguiente:

Al momento de pasar el cursor sobre Cualquier Widget se imprimiera el nombre del widget por ejemplo QPushButton o algun mensaje de ayuda

Para ello trate de implementar la funcion `mouseMoveEvent` y adicionalmente "QLabel" como una especie de ToolTip pero no funciona:

espero puedan ayudarme:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class CustomToolTip(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.boton = QPushButton(self)
        self.boton.setText("Boton")
        self.Tool = QLabel(self.boton)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,event,object):
        if object:
            self.toolTip.setText("Ayuda")
            self.toolTip.move((event.x()-5),(event.y()-5))
            self.toolTip.show()
        else:
            self.toolTip.hide()

app = QApplication([])
cm = CustomToolTip()
cm.show()
cm.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder solucionar este problema hay que tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Bajo el mouse pueden estar varios widgets ya que Qt tiene una pila de ellos, asi que la solucion debe ser obtener esos widgets.
- Para que un widget se dibuje dentro de otro widget el primero debe ser hijo del segundo.
- Para saber si un widget esta bajo el mouse puedes usar el método underMouse().
- El evento del mouse se informa primero al widget superior y despues si es habilitado a el widget inferior, asi que se debe habilitar el mouseTracking a todos los widgets hijos, directos o indirectos, de la misma forma se debe instalar el filtro de eventos.
- Para obtener los hijos de un widget debes usar el método findChildren().
- Para obtener el nombre de la clase se puede usar el metodo className() del QMetaObject.
- Para que un widget se comporte como un tooltip debes habilitar el flag Qt::QToolTip, ademas que su posicion es respecto a la pantalla.

Considerando todo lo anterior, he implementado una clase externa que rastrea la pocisión del mouse dentro de la ventana, ademas he añadido un ejemplo más complejo:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLineEdit())
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Text"), alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QComboBox())
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTextEdit())
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10))

        self.addToolBar("toolbar")
        self.statusBar().showMessage("message")
        self.menuBar().addMenu("menu1")
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, QtWidgets.QDockWidget())
        self.resize(640, 480)


class ToolTipManager(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, widget, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_widget = widget
        self.m_counter = 0
        self.m_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.m_widget, flags=QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)
        self.register_widget()

    def register_widget(self):
        for w in self.m_widget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget) + [self.m_widget]:
            w.setMouseTracking(True)
            w.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.update_tooltip()
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def update_tooltip(self):
        widgets = []
        for w in self.m_widget.findChildren(QtWidgets.QWidget) + [self.m_widget]:
            if w.underMouse():
                widgets.append(w)
        text = "\n".join([w.metaObject().className() for w in widgets])
        self.m_label.setText(text)
        self.m_label.adjustSize()
        self.m_label.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos() + QtCore.QPoint(5, 5))
        self.m_label.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    o = ToolTipManager(w)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
``
```